# websocket gracefully shutdown

Tags: go, websocket

I have a websocket server. I wrote a test for him that tests his ability to shutdown gracefully. 5 connections are created and each sends 5 requests. After a while, shutdown starts. All 25 requests must be fulfilled. If I close the `exit` channel, then the test does not work as it should.

```
    time.AfterFunc(50*time.Millisecond, func() {
        close(exit)
        close(done)
    })
```

And if I just call the `s.shutdown` function, then everything is ok.

```
    time.AfterFunc(50*time.Millisecond, func() {
        require.Nil(t, s.Shutdown())
        close(done)
    })
```

My test

```
func TestServer_GracefulShutdown(t *testing.T) {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    exit := make(chan struct{})
    ctx := context.Background()

    finishedRequestCount := atomic.NewInt32(0)
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:")
    require.Nil(t, err)

    handler := HandlerFunc(func(conn *websocket.Conn) {
        for {
            _, _, err := conn.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            finishedRequestCount.Inc()
        }
    })
    s, err := makeServer(ctx, handler) // server create
    require.Nil(t, err)
    time.AfterFunc(50*time.Millisecond, func() {
        close(exit)
        close(done)
    })
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("Running...")
        require.Nil(t, s.Run(ctx, exit, ln))
    }()
    for i := 0; i < connCount; i++ {
        go func() {
            err := clientRun(ln)
            require.Nil(t, err)
        }()
    }

    <-done

    assert.Equal(t, int32(totalCount), finishedRequestCount.Load())
}
```

My run func

```
func (s *Server) Run(ctx context.Context, exit <-chan struct{}, ln net.Listener) error {
    errs := make(chan error, 1)

    go func() {
        err := s.httpServer.Run(ctx, exit, ln)
        if err != nil {
            errs <- err
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return s.Close()
    case <-exit:
        return s.Shutdown()
    case err := <-errs:
        return err
    }
}
```

My shutdown

```
func (s *Server) Shutdown() error {
    err := s.httpServer.Shutdown() // we close the possibility to connect to any conn
    s.wg.Wait()
    return err
}
```

Comment: You already have a context, so why have an extra close channel?

Comment: s.Close() just close server, s.Shutdown close gracefully with waiting for close frame from clients

Comment: Instead of the close channel, wrap the context in a `context.WithCancel` and use the returned `cancel` function to cancel the context. Contexts were built to remove the need of close channels.

Comment: If you need different behaviour, have different contexts building on each other. The context for the graceful `Shutdown` can be created internally.

Comment: First step I'd do is create a clean API for your `Server`. How do you want to use it? Make that as simple and expressive as possible. Right now you are exposing too many internals (or knowledge about internals) in your API. In my opinion, the Server should do graceful shutdown on its own, or if you need to have both, offer `Shutdown` and `GracefulShutdown` and the second one could block until things are shut down.

Comment: `s.Close()` function that shutdown the server without waiting.
You're right about API. I'm just starting to write them. Why do you think just `s.Shutdown()` works as it should, but `close(exit)` doesn't?

Comment: That is not really what I meant... Looking at the code I can see it seems `Shutdown` is not meant to be called from the outside. If called, it would not release the Go routine that is blocked on the `select` in `Run`. If that is correct, it should be an internal function `shutdown`.

Comment: BTW: which channel are you talking about here: "If I close the `close' channel..."

Comment: sorry, `exit` channel. We were talking about something else :(

Comment: See my investigation below in the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening if the following code is executed?

```golang
close(exit)
close(done)
```

Both channels are closed almost at the same time. The first triggers the `Shutdown` function which waits for a graceful shutdown. But the second triggers the evaluation of

```golang
assert.Equal(t, int32(totalCount), finishedRequestCount.Load())
```

It is triggered while the graceful shutdown is still running or hasn't even started yet.

---

If you execute the Shutdown function directly it will block until finished and only then `close(done)` will start the assertion. That is why this works:

```golang
require.Nil(t, s.Shutdown())
close(done)
```

---

You can move the `close(done)` to the following location to make the test work while using the `exit` channel to close:

```golang
go func() {
    fmt.Printf("Running...")
    require.Nil(t, s.Run(ctx, exit, ln))
    close(done)
}()
```

This way `done` will be closed after the `Shutdown` function was executed.

---

As discussed in the comments I strongly suggest to use contexts instead of channels to close. They have the complexity of close channels hidden away.